# Custom JSON Service

Tags: json, liferay

Any clues how can we develop a Custom JSON Service.

We dont have a service.xml since internally the service will be invoking liferay services for retrieving activities.
 From our portlet we want to invoke this Custom JSON Service through Ajax and display the result.

We dont want to use serveResource.

Regards,
 Tina

Comment: What do you want this service to do? "retrieving activities" and "display the result" is too vague.

Answer (score 0):

use the XMLHttpRequest() object:

```
<%@include file="include.jsp"%>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function <portlet:namespace/>myService() {
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
//...
var url = "<%=request.getContextPath()%>/myCustomJSONService";
xhr.open("GET", url, true);
xhr.send();
}
</script>
<table>
<tr>
<td><b><a href="#"
<!--Creates Refresh hyperlink-->
onclick="<portlet:namespace/>myService();"
style="color: black;">Refresh</a></b></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br/>
<div id="<portlet:namespace/>messageText">
</div>
```

Here myCustomJSONService could be a servlet that sends some JSON data to a user.

See A. Sarin: Portlets in Action, Chapter 12.2.3: "Handling Ajax requests using portlet or servlet components"